# Variable returns undefined within a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var modelNumber = false;
  var Description = false;

  $('#step-two-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    modelNumber = $("#model-number-field").val();
    Description = $("#description-field").val();

    alert(modelNumber); //undefined
    alert(Description); //undefined
  });

});
```

Can anyone tell me why the following variables are returning undefined? I have defined global variables but jquery does not seem to recognize them.

Comment: Can you post your html as well??

Comment: It's undefined because you have no markup. You need to add your markup here so the question can be answered.

Comment: @iscmaro seems like the id in the markup was invalid, that solved my issue! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working as expected when you set up your HTML like

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var modelNumber = false;
  var Description = false;


  $('#step-two-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modelNumber = $("#model-number-field").val();
    Description = $("#description-field").val();
    alert(modelNumber); //undefined
    alert(Description); //undefined
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="model-number-field">
<input type="text" id="description-field">
<button id="step-two-btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alerting the variables, try:

```
alert($("#model-number-field").length);
alert($("#description-field").length);
```

If both return 0, then it isn't finding your element by the ID.  Double-check the HTML markup.  Note: I'm not saying this as a permanent solution, just a quick test to do the verification.

Comment: Right, the issue was it wasnt finding the ID. Thank you for your help!